# How to control versioning in Django Rest Framework (DRF)

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, drf-nested-routers

I want to know what is the best practices for controlling the Version for Mobile App APIs.

**Requirement**

- If I change something in my database previous version of the app should not be affected.

- Currently I'm doing like...

```
path('v1/auth/', include('authentication.urls')),
path('v2/auth/', include('authentication.urls2')), # Example
path('v1/api/', include('contentstudio.urls')),
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Django REST Framework has support for many different methods of versioning you api. Check out the [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/versioning/) to find which one suits you best.

According to the docs, the `AcceptHeaderVersioning` method *"is generally considered as best practice"*. ie. you put the version in the Accept header like so:

```
Accept: application/json; version=1.0
```

Using any of these methods you will have access to `request.version` in your views to determine the behavior of the different versions.